# How to find out what database is linked to a certain ID in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

Basically, I have a VB.NET project with which I connect to a remote MySQL server.

The credentials that I can provide would be "server ip", "port", "database ID", "username" and "password".

Pretty basic stuff, except for the fact that it's the DB ID that's given and not the actual DB name. How can I retrieve the name of the database which is linked to that ID?

Currently I use this connection string to connect to it

`connection.ConnectionString = "Host=" & server & ";port=" & port & ";user=" & uname & ";password=" & pword & ";"`

Note: The reason I need to be able to have these in variables is because I plan to distribute this tool to some friends of mine, which have a different MySQL server to connect to, with different database names etc. And because not everyone needs to know what the database is called, due to safety reasons.

Edit: Another thing I could do is have my program check every database on the server and return which database has a certain table in it, then use that output for the rest of my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround, although this might not be applicable to other MySQL databases.

Here's how I did it:

```
Public Function sqlConnectTest(ByVal server, port, instance, uname, pword) As Boolean
    Dim connection As MySqlConnection
    connection = New MySqlConnection()
    connection.ConnectionString = "Host=" & server & ";port=" & port & _
";user=" & uname & ";password=" & pword & ";"
    Try
        connection.Open()
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Opened Successfully")
        **Dim stm As String = "SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA from information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_NAME like 'survivor'"**
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(stm, connection)
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        While reader.Read()
            DBname = reader.GetString(0)
        End While
        reader.Close()
        connection.Close()
        Return True
    Catch mysql_error As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error Connecting to Database: " & mysql_error.Message)
        Return False
    Finally
        connection.Dispose()
    End Try
End Function
```

Obviously this solution would only work when you have an information_schema database, containing a table which shows all the tables in all the databases on the server.